# JSON output prints only the last result

Tags: jquery, json, html-lists, each

I have a JSON data similar to structure below :

```
{"error":false,"gal_providers":[{

"GalProvider":{
"id":"132",
"uid":"gp_522f1e047329f",
"user_id":"49754",
"author_id":"0"
},

"User":{
"id":"49754",
"uid":"516fe0addefb0",
"name":"Abhishek Sarkar Photography"
},

"GalLocation":{"id":"1","name":"Delhi - NCR","show_in_list":"1","status":"1"},

"GalStore":[]},

{
"GalProvider":{
"id":"53",
"uid":"gp_522f1e0471886",
"user_id":"32643",
"author_id":"28449"
},

"User":{
"id":"32643",
"uid":"50ced38d99754",
"name":"Amar Ramesh"
},

"GalLocation":{"id":"1","name":"Delhi - NCR","show_in_list":"1","status":"1"},


"GalStore":[]}]}
```

And the jquery function I am retrieving the data is :

```
function render_result(resp){

var page_num = 1;
    jQuery.each(resp.gal_providers, function(index, gal_provider) {

        var pagename = gal_provider.User.name.replace(/\s/g , "-");


        html = "";

        html += '<li class="card boxcard">';
        html += '<a href="http://localhost/myshaadi/gallery/photographer/'+gal_provider.GalProvider.id+'/'+pagename+'"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/myshaadi/backup/images/gallery/cover/'+gal_provider.GalProvider.cover_img+ '" class="cover_image" alt=""/></a>';
        html += '<div class="card_info">';            
        html += '<div class="title" style="height:auto">';
        html += '<a href="" class="single-line">'+gal_provider.User.name+'</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</li>';

        $("#search_result").html(html);

        page_num++;
    });

    alert(page_num);
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<ul id="search_result" class="col-3">

</ul>
```

Although it alerts `3`, it displays only one result ! Whats wrong with the loop ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the

```
html = "";
```

from inside the cicle

you are resetting the html var every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you are using `html()` to overwrite the previous contents of the div, you can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add new elements to the existing contents

```
function render_result(resp) {

    var page_num = 1;
     $("#search_result").html('');
    jQuery.each(resp.gal_providers, function (index, gal_provider) {

        var pagename = gal_provider.User.name.replace(/\s/g, "-");


        html = "";

        html += '<li class="card boxcard">';
        html += '<a href="http://localhost/myshaadi/gallery/photographer/' + gal_provider.GalProvider.id + '/' + pagename + '"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/myshaadi/backup/images/gallery/cover/' + gal_provider.GalProvider.cover_img + '" class="cover_image" alt=""/></a>';
        html += '<div class="card_info">';
        html += '<div class="title" style="height:auto">';
        html += '<a href="" class="single-line">' + gal_provider.User.name + '</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</li>';

        $("#search_result").append(html);

        page_num++;
    });

    alert(page_num);
}
```

Another solution is to append all the html to the `html` variable inside the loop and then append the html to the container after the loop like

```
function render_result(resp) {

    var page_num = 1;
    var html = '';
    jQuery.each(resp.gal_providers, function (index, gal_provider) {

        var pagename = gal_provider.User.name.replace(/\s/g, "-");

        html += '<li class="card boxcard">';
        html += '<a href="http://localhost/myshaadi/gallery/photographer/' + gal_provider.GalProvider.id + '/' + pagename + '"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/myshaadi/backup/images/gallery/cover/' + gal_provider.GalProvider.cover_img + '" class="cover_image" alt=""/></a>';
        html += '<div class="card_info">';
        html += '<div class="title" style="height:auto">';
        html += '<a href="" class="single-line">' + gal_provider.User.name + '</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</li>';

        page_num++;
    });

    $("#search_result").html(html);
}
```

Comment: `append()` makes non results come. second method results same !